# Plotting y-axis out of order in Pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, weather-api

I have the following program:

```
from weather import Weather
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

weather = Weather()

highTemp = []
lowTemp = []

city = input('Enter the city for weather forecast \n: ')


location = weather.lookup_by_location(city)
condition = location.condition

print("The weather forecast for",city,"is",condition.text)

forecast = location.forecast
for forecast in forecast:
    forecasthigh = forecast.high  
    forecastlow = forecast.low
    print(forecast.date)      
    print("High temperature:",forecast.high)
    print("forecast.low",forecast.low)
    print(forecast.text)   

    highTemp.append(forecasthigh)
    lowTemp.append(forecastlow)
    #plt.axis([1,10,0,40])
    plt.plot(highTemp, '-r',lowTemp,'-b')
    plt.ylabel('Temperature')
    plt.xlabel('Days')
    plt.pause(0.05)
    print("----------------------------------------------")
plt.show
```

The program shows the weather forecast using the Weather-API. I wanted to plot the high and low temperature variations for the occurring days. The problem is that the Y-label plots out of order causing the graph to go all over the place.

Is there a way to better plot the graph or define the Y-axis ?

Comment: The values are probably strings. What is the result of `print(type(forecasthigh))`?

Comment: @DavidG <class 'str'>

Comment: You need to convert them to numbers (ints or floats) before appending to the list

Comment: Parsed the values of forecast.high to int. Everything working! Thanks for the help!